# Pop up image on mouse hover

Tags: asp.net, popup, mouseover

I am using asp.net 2.0 and c#.

I have a datagrid in which I have a image control, i.e.

```
<asp:Image ID="ImagePreview" runat="server"  Width="62px" Height="62px" />
```

for which I am setting the image URL from code behind, i.e.the image exist in the physical folder. 
I want to open a pop up with the image on mousehover.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Kindly let me know if any other information is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use JavaScript for this:

```
ImagePreview.Attributes.Item("onMouseOver") = "javascript:window.open('localhost','newWindow','width=200,height=200')";
```

Comment: Do I have to write the same code between <Script> tag ? I am very weak in javascript, that's why I post this question here. Sorry to trouble you.

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery Tooltips, you can put the image preview in the tooltip.
http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html

I've implemented this in a column in a GridView control and it works great

Comment: Hi Ed,

This page is coming as encrypted page in my browser.