# How to make picture bigger when i move the mouse on her?

Tags: c#, asp.net

in my asp.net webform i have image that hold picture

how to make this picture bigger when i move the mouse on her ?

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried so far?

Here's some pseudocode JavaScriptish:
`onMouseOver = "img.width = new_x; img.height = new_y;" onMouseOut = "img.width = original_x; img.height = original_y;"

Note that this will only scale the picture, resulting in poor quality depending on how much you "make it bigger".

Comment: this what i need !!!  but how to write it in my project ? and where ?  i have Image1 that contain the picture.  thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can't make the picture bigger with same picture quality. 
Normally in web application to show up in page you have to use a Thumbnail image and in the hover you have to use a bigger image loaded in DIV or something.

[Pop up image on mouse hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229134/pop-up-image-on-mouse-hover)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Lightbox which give you a popup with you full image when clicking a thumbnail.

You could always trigger the event that show the picture on mouseover tough I wouldn't recommend it.

http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/